# Macport-installed python can't find macport-installed sip

Tags: qt, pyqt4, macports

I am learning PyQt4 by reading **Rapid GUI Programming with Python and Qt** and am at chapter 7 which covers QT Designer; however QT Designer doesn't appear to be installed with my MacPort's (py34-pyqt4) or the example code from the book's website [www.qtrac.eu](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html). So I'm downloading QT Designer from [www.qt.io](http://www.qt.io/developers/).

The straightforward installation (`python configure-ng.py`, `make`, `make install`) hangs on the configure step complaining

```
Error: Make sure you have a working sip on your PATH or use the --sip argument
to explicitly specify a working sip.
```

I am hoping MacPorts has `sip`, and luckily `port search sip` finds `py34-sip`. However after installing, getting the same error, and finding `port installed` lists `py34-sip` as installed; I check my default python.

```
$ which python
/opt/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 3.4.3
$ port contents py34-sip
...
/opt/local/bin/sip-3.4
...
```

Good, we are in the MacPorts-python34 universe, but why isn't python finding `py34-sip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Macport should have been able to use its own tools, it needed some help. Reading the error message and consulting

```
python configure-ng.py --help
```

gave me the solution

```
python configure-ng.py --sip /opt/local/bin/sip-3.4
```

which lead to a successful compilation.